# Download attachments from Yammer

Tags: yammer

I am using Web Client to download yammer attachments i tried to use all different URL's available by yammer API / browser :

-download URL
-large preview URL
-right click and copy image URL

file is downloaded with 0 bytes

any suggestion ?

Comment: You'll have to provide more details. What exactly is the request you're making to download those files (incl. authentication)?

Comment: I am using yammer API to retrieve messages form yammer , the message object has attachments list , each attachment has "download URL" and preview URL , i need to download this attachment on my local machine 

what i am doing is trying to download attachments using that URL without any authentication, i only used authentication and token to retrieve messages details.

Download Url https://www.yammer.com/api/v1/uploaded_files/21299410/download 

Preview URL

Comment: i think i need to give authentication with the download link , but i have no idea how to do this ?

i am getting 401 error

Comment: The issue is that you're trying to download a protected resource without authenticating. That same token you used to query the Yammer API for messages needs to be provided to download the files.

Which platform are you writing code on? Which mechanism are you using to query the API today?

Comment: I am using C# , I am using WEBClient to download files

 WebClient client = new WebClient();
            client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
            client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL),FileName);

Comment: this was my missing part in Code, thank you for help
as you said i need to pass access token with dwonload url so ican have access to that resource.
client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;

Answer (score 1, accepted):

to download Yammer attachments you need both Download URl and Access token as below

```
  string Path = @"C:\SocialMediaDownloads\Yammer\Attachments\"+MessageId; 
  bool isExists = System.IO.Directory.Exists(Path);
  if (!isExists)
        System.IO.Directory.CreateDirectory(Path);

        WebClient client = new WebClient();
        client.BaseAddress = "https://www.yammer.com";
        client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Bearer " + accessToken;
        client.DownloadFileCompleted += new AsyncCompletedEventHandler(client_DownloadDataCompleted);
        client.DownloadFileAsync(new Uri(URL),Path+@"\"+FileName);
        return Path;
    }
```

Comment: Is it possible to add the accessToken when placing the image url in an <img/> tag?